# Windows IoT Remote Client lag

Tags: windows-10, iot

I notice a substantial lag when using the Windows IoT Remote Client. Is there a way to optimize this?

at this moment this is negatively performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer to improve the performance is just to use a HDMI cable instead. The Windows IoT Remote Client is officially still in preview so they may improve it.

There are lots of other ways to control your Windows IoT Core device. Without really needing the RDP style client.

Here's a blog post that explores the other options you have to control your device.

http://www.purplefrogsystems.com/paul/2016/06/controlling-your-windows-10-iot-core-device/

Personally the browser based console does everything I need. Seeing the devices actual display doesn't really add much. Its really just for information.